# Sending an email in metro application?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to send an email with some content as a body in my metro app :-

1)since system.net.mail is not supported in metro application i have decided to use this :-

```
using Windows.System;
//starts the default mail app with a subject, cc, bcc, and body
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:windows8devs@almostbeta.com?subject=Code Request&cc=kevin@almostbeta.com&bcc=admin@almostbeta.com&body=Hi!"));
```

but my doubt is that i want to generate a content as a body to this email , but this content is of html type , i mean this body is of type html (specifiying some text or content in between the html tags)

Please let me know how can i do this , i.e setting a simple html type body to as a body to this email which i would like to send through my application.

Am i going wrong , pls let me know and correct me if i am wrong .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't send emails. Let the user share the content using the 'Share' charm.

Comment: It's not so simply ZippyV. There are tons of scenarios when you specifically need to use email - for example to email support when you need to specify both the address and some content. The charms don't have support for this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email story in WinStore apps is pretty broken right now. You can either use mailto: with no content or use share charms with no email details. I suspect they must enable support for some email document contracts at some point in the future, but I don't think it is available yet.

*EDIT

It also sounds like a great opportunity for someone to write a web service to send emails if a good one doesn't already exist. You could of course write one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct usage of the Win8/Metro design language.  You want to enable support for the "Share Source" contract.  Here is the link to the sample/support for how to use the sharing contract:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782

It lets you specify a body (content), though the user could also choose to share it to something other than mail, and you don't get to specify an email address.  There are several email sending services out there, and that might be a better solution if the user doesn't have to edit the email before it is sent.