# Sending Email in Metro Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, microsoft-metro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending an email in metro application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969059/sending-an-email-in-metro-application)

In my metro style app using c# and xaml i need to send en email. How can i send emails in metro apps that similar to EmailComposeTask in Windows phone. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you could post the code that you have tried and describe what it is exactly that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8 you can use the [Share contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758315.aspx) which allows you to share content from your application.

Therefore, apps installed which are accepting share (you can choose different sharing format like HTML) can be used to share content of your application like the mail app.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Launcher to invoke the default email client

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:recipient@example.com"); 
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

You can also fill in the subject or text

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=recipient@example.com&subject=Your subject&body=Your text"); 
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```